# What is the splitting field of $t^4+2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I currently beginning the study if Galois theory but my understanding of the construction of splitting fields could be better. So I must ask if I could see the steps in constructing the splitting field of $t^4+2$.

Comment: The field is generated by the four roots of the polynomial. Do you know them?

Answer (score 3):

A splitting field of a polynomial must be computed *over* a field, and the choice of that field affects the resulting splitting field, since a splitting field is a field extension.

For instance, the splitting field of $t^4 + 2$ over $\mathbb R$ is $\mathbb C = \mathbb R(i)$.  The splitting field of that same polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ is something else (hinted by an above comment).  And the splitting field of that same polynomial over $\mathbb F_7$ is again something else.

Answer (score 3):

First You must determine that the polynomial is considered to be in $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ or any other field.

I suppose that we're going to find the splitting field of $t^4+2\in\mathbb{Q}[t]$.

Now you know $\mathbb{C}$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. This is a good start that every polynomial splits in $\mathbb{C}$.

Then let's try to split it!
$$t^4+2=(t-\sqrt[4]{2}\omega)(t-\sqrt[4]{2}\omega^3)(t-\sqrt[4]{2}\omega^5)(t-\sqrt[4]{2}\omega^7);$$ 
where $\omega=e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}$.

[image]

Now it's sufficient to form the field $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}\omega,\sqrt[4]{2}\omega^3,\sqrt[4]{2}\omega^5,\sqrt[4]{2}\omega^7)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}\omega,\omega^2)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}\omega,i)$

The last line is true as @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez♦ has mentioned in the comments.

---

#EDITED

It's definitely wrong that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}\omega,\sqrt[4]{2}\omega^3,\sqrt[4]{2}\omega^5,\sqrt[4]{2}\omega^7)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}\omega)$, as @Jyrki Lahtonen♦ has stated in the comment below.

Comment: How do you justify the claim on the last line? You seem to be saying that the splitting field is a degree four extension of the rational. But IMO even the real subfield is quartic as it contains
$$\root4\of2(\omega+\omega^7)=\sqrt2\root4\of2.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Definitely I was wrong. Thanks for your notice

Comment: Notice that $i=\omega^2$ is in the field, as it is the quotient of two «succesive» roots. You can check that the field is $Q(\sqrt[4]2\omega,i)$.

Comment: yes, you're right